# Unable to drop a user

Tags: oracle

I want to drop a user like 'salman'. I have tried this syntax:

```
drop user "'salman'"
```

but it is not dropping.

Secondly, I want to drop a single database by command not from dbca. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you wrote `drop user "salman"` or `drop user salman`?

Comment: What error did you get? Privileges, or user doesn't exist?

Comment: What user do you want to drop SALMAN, 'salman' or salman

Answer (score 4):

You may need the DROP USER system privilege.  But if you have that, the syntax should be:

```
DROP USER salman;
```

If you want to drop the user and all of the objects he owns:

```
DROP USER salman CASCADE;
```